# How to sub-divide Mendeley reference list

Tags: ms-word, reference, citations, mendeley

I am using Mendeley as a reference manager in MS Word and I am wondering about a specific format of reference organization. I would like my reference list to have a "nested" format, where each reference is subdivided (using a,b,c,... for example) instead of having separate references (1, 2, 3, ...).

I am currently using the standard referencing format "Angewandte Chemie International Edition" [[link]](https://csl.mendeley.com/visualEditor/?styleUrl=http://www.zotero.org/styles/angewandte-chemie). I am using this reference style through the Mendeley MS Word plugin. Do I have to change something in the reference style itself, should I change a setting in MS Word?

Right, now my referencing/citation style looks like this:

> This is how my references look now. [1,2,3]
>
> **References**
>
> [1] J. L. Campbell, O. K. Pedersen, Comp. Polit. Stud. 2007, 40, 307–332.
>
> [2] M. D. McInnis, L. P. Nelson, Shaping the Body Politic: Art and Political Formation in Early America, University Of Virginia Press, Charlottesville, VA, 2011.
>
> [3] “CSL search by example,” can be found under http://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/, n.d.

I would like it to look like this:

> This is how I would like my references look. [1]
>
> **References**
>
> [1] a) J. L. Campbell, O. K. Pedersen, Comp. Polit. Stud. 2007, 40, 307–332. b) M. D. McInnis, L. P. Nelson, Shaping the Body Politic: Art and Political Formation in Early America, University Of Virginia Press, Charlottesville, VA, 2011. c) “CSL search by example,” can be found under http://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/, n.d.

Thanks in advance for any & all tips!